# Can CodeIgniter route to different controllers based on port number?

Tags: php, codeigniter, port, codeigniter-url, codeigniter-routing

I would like to have CodeIgniter route to a different controller based on port number like so:

```
host_name/ControllerName      => foo() 
host_name:3000/ControllerName => bar()
```

I've added port 3000 to Apache's httpd.conf, so the server listens to both, but how do you tell CodeIgniter to route to a different method based on the port number? I was thinking that something like

```
$route[":3000/test/index"] = "ControllerName/bar"
```

would work, but no.

I've searched StackOverflow as well as [the official documentation](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html), but no luck.

Anyone have an idea, or is port-based routing just not supported by the framework?

Comment: Improved formatting for easier readability. Fixed minor spelling issue. Shortened title and body where possible in order to improve reader engagement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `$_SERVER['SERVER_PORT']` to get port number and then write conditional routing in route.php